# Ruby script to check if a string is within a file?

Tags: ruby, bash, csv, awk

I have **CSV file** of words and their frequencies as well as a **.txt file** containing several words of interest, separated by newlines.

I'm looking for a way to check if, for every row of the CSV, the first column value (the word) is also in the .txt file.

I guess something similar to `fgrep -x -f patternfile.txt data.csv` except with only 1 column of the CSV rather than the entire row?

Comment: Is your problem how to read the CSV, how to loop over the rows, or how to read if a file has a string?

Comment: Can you please show how your CSV file is structured? This should be easy with an awk script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk` you can do something like this -

```
awk -v FS="," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]}' csv_file txt_file
```

- Set the Field Separator to `,`
- Using the first column (word) of your csv file as an index load the entire line in an array.
- Check if the value of text file is in the array.
- If it is then print it

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/Temp] cat csv_file 
jack,4
rabbit,10
cat,4
red,39

[jaypal:~/Temp] cat txt_file 
red
rabbit
cat

[jaypal:~/Temp] awk -v FS="," 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in a){print a[$1]}' csv_file txt_file
red,39
rabbit,10
cat,4
```

Answer (score 4):

Hey You can use FasterCSV to open and loop thru the records.

```
        FasterCSV.foreach("#{file_path}") do |row| 
        puts row[0]#row[0] is the first column only
        end
```

Answer (score 2):

To check if a file has a particular string in it at least once:

```
IO.readlines(filename).map(&:chomp).include?("somestring")
```

Answer (score 2):

If we are using bash, than it will be:

```
fgrep -x -f patternfile.txt data.csv | awk '{print $2}'
```

as a simplies way to get second column from a grep results

Comment: What if patternfile only constrains strings that match with the second column of the CSV? As in, I want the entire CSV row printed at the end, but only those where the second column value is included within patternfile.txt?

Comment: For the CSV: red,5
For the text file: red

Comment: @AmyLi In the question you have posted the second value as word.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry! That was my mistake for the typo. :) But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To combine [Phrogz's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9015083/7552) and [yatish's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9015115/7552) answers:

```
require 'csv'
words = File.readlines("words.txt").map(&:chomp)
CSV::foreach("data.csv") {|row| puts row.to_csv if words.include?(row[0])}
```